# Blazor WASM LayoutComponentBase with @Body and more properties

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor, blazor-client-side

My use case is I have the MainLayout.razor with this code

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<header><nav ....></header>
<section><h1>Page Title</h1><section>
<main class="container">
    <div class="row"><div class="col-12">@Body</div></div>
</main>
```

Now I want to set the page title from every @Body razor fragment (maybe by inheritance)

```
@page "/about"
<div>....</div>
@code {
    Title = "About Title";
}
```

I want avoid to put `<section>` inside the @body fragment.
Also have the same problem with the title-element from head-element. What is best practices to do this (without js interop)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do that...

- Using CascadingValue feature
  Define a property in MainLayout to get the title from child components such as 
  the about component.

  Add a CascadingValue component to MainLayout, and pass the MainLayout component 
  as the value of the Value attribute.

  In the child component define a CascadingParameter property which stores the 
  MainLayout object, and assign a title to its Title property

  Here's the full code:

### MainLayout

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
        <h1>@Title</h1>
        <LoginDisplay />
        <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">
        <CascadingValue Value="this">
           @Body
        </CascadingValue>
   </div>

</div>

@code
{
  string title;

  public string Title
 {
    get => title;
    set
    {
        if(title != value)
        { 
            title = value;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
     }
  }
}
```

### About.razor

```
@page "/about"
<div>....</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public MainLayout MainLayout { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
   {

      MainLayout.Title = "About Title";

   }
 }
```

- Create a service class that defines a Title property that can be set by 
  components into which the service is injected. This service class should also provide a way to pass the title supplied by child components to the MainLayout, which should refresh itself in order to display the provided title...

Hope this helps...